# How to prove that $\mathbb{R}$ is not artinian, considered as a $\mathbb{Q}$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

How can I prove that the set $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers as a $\mathbb{Q}$-module is not artinian?

I have tried to prove it, by the irrationals, but I could not prove it.

Answer (score 10):

If you are thinking about things like the irrationals then you may be missing the forest for the trees.  I suggest you take a step back and try to show the following result.

> Let $K$ be a field and let $V$ be a $K$-module -- i.e., a $K$-vector space.  The following are equivalent:
>   (i) $V$ is finitely generated (in other words, finite-dimensional) over $K$.
>   (ii) $V$ is Noetherian.
>   (iii) $V$ is Artinian.
>   (iv) $V$ admits a composition series, i.e., a maximal proper chain of submodules
>   $0 = V_0 \subsetneq V_1 \subsetneq \ldots \subsetneq V_n = V$.

Note also that the fact that these equivalent conditions are not satisfied for $\mathbb{R}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space follows from the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is an uncountably infinite set.

Final comment: more generally, for a ring $R$, the above conditions on a left $R$-module are equivalent iff $R$ is left Artinian.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** The dimension of $\Bbb R$ over $\Bbb Q$ is infinite, so you can find some sequence $\langle r_i\mid i\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be linearly independent over $\Bbb Q$, use this sequence to generate a sequence of decreasing modules without a minimum.

Comment: Can I take it to be the set that is generated by square roots of primes

Comment: @user70330: You can take this set to be any set that you want, as long as it is countably infinite, and linearly independent over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @Jmath: yes, the set $\{ \sqrt{p} \}$ as $p$ ranges over all prime numbers is countably infinite and linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, as can be shown by some basic (not completely trivial) field theory.  But in some sense this is more work than you need to do: just knowing that $\# \mathbb{R} > \# \mathbb{Q}$ is enough to show that $\mathbb{R}$ is infinite-dimensional (indeed, of uncountably infinite dimension) over $\mathbb{Q}$.